# pipe() is either not writing correctly, not reading correctly, or both

Tags: c, pipe

I am trying to get a pipe working between two children where they can communicate with each other, but it doesn't seem to be reading/writing anything.

My output looks like this:

```
(Parent pid:1)
(First child pid:2)
(Second child pid:3)
What is your sibling's pid? Answer: 0
```

this is the code that i have for it, but it all looks like it should work.

EDIT: i added some checks to see if the pipe, write, or read were failing, but not getting any of those errors. it seems like the pipe is working, but still shows a 0 for the answer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int rc = fork();
    int pipeArr[2];
    if(pipe(pipeArr) == -1) {
        printf("An error ocurred when opening pipe\n");
    }

    if(rc < 0) {
        // fork failed
        fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else if(rc == 0) {
        // child (new process)
        close(pipeArr[0]); // this is the output, not needed here
        int pid = (int) getpid();
        printf("(First child pid:%d)\n", pid);
        
        if(write(pipeArr[1], &pid, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            printf("An error ocurred when writing to the pipe\n");
        }

        close(pipeArr[1]); // this is the input, not needed anymore
    }
    else {
        // parent goes down this path (main)
        printf("(Parent pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
        int rc2 = fork();

        if(rc2 < 0) {
            // fork failed
            fprintf(stderr, "fork failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if(rc2 == 0) {
            // child (new process)
            close(pipeArr[1]); // this is the input, not needed here
            int pid;
            
            if(read(pipeArr[0], &pid, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
                printf("An error ocurred when reading from the pipe\n");
            }

            close(pipeArr[0]); // this is the output, not needed anymore

            printf("(Second child pid:%d)\n", (int) getpid());
            printf("What is the first child's pid? Answer: %d\n", pid);
        }
        else {
            // nothing needed here
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Think about the *order* in which you do things. When and where and in which process (or perhaps process***es***) do you create the pipe? Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) might be useful here. Also don't forget to check if `pipe` actually succeeds, same with your `read` and `write` calls.

Comment: You didn't actually fix the major problem which was hinted at in the first part of the previous comment. Explicitly - you need to create the pipe *before* forking. As it is, each process is creating a seperate pipe.

Comment: ah, well that would do it then... lol I didn't realize that you needed to create the pipe before forking

Comment: That's why they call it "education" and not just "picking up your doctorate". Learning C is more a journey than a race `:)`